# Rest Console for Chrome won't let me input any info

Tags: rest, google-chrome

I installed the [Rest Console extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn) onto Chrome. I can't use this Rest Console for anything, because the only fields that accept text are 'Request URL' and 'Request Method'.

I ask here as there is no resources or community accessible for even simple instructions on how this extension works, and there are likely members of this community who have used this extension.

Comment: Hello, I'm the developer of REST Console and I'm really sorry you're running into troubles using it ... I'm not sure what the "no smoking symbol" is, but I would love if you can share some screenshots of what you are experiencing so I can help you through it and if there is a bug, help solve it for other people as well. can you also please share the browser and operating system details as Chrome does have some minor differences between OSs.

Comment: Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit, Google Chrome Version 22.0.1229.94 m. Unfortunately my screenshots are not showing the grayed out text boxes or my mouse cursor, which is what turns into a little no smoking sign when it overs over a text field. Google 'no smoking sign', it's the same but without the cigarette.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [Postman - REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) it works perfectly!

```
your_url_to_post: Fill the URL    
your_json_param: The name of the param that you'll pass you json    
your_json_data: The json content
```

Don't forget to select x-www-form-urlencoded if you'll do a post

[image: Postman-picture]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TISW1.png

Comment: I don't see any where I can insert my json data. How does this work?

Comment: Just added a picture explaining how to do it! Hope it helps!

Comment: Well, close enough. I need to figure out the name of my json parameter but at least this works!

Comment: By the way,  x-www-form-urlencoded did not work for a post. Only raw did

Comment: Actually I already used x-www-form-urlencoded for posting! Maybe you scenario don't allow to use the x-www-form-urlencoded but it work for posts ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to enter text in the other field if you **tick the checkbox** associated to the field first.

[image]

Comment: This does not work. A ticked checkbox does not allow me to enter text into it's associated field. Instead, when I hover over the field a pleasant no smoking symbol appears.

Answer (score 0):

I started having a similar issue myself (Forms wouldnt let me input data I could click them but thats as far as it went) across a lot of web pages to include my own php game and I know the form code hasnt changed at all before this issue started.  I came across a article of someone else having a similar issue themselves that I was having and someone said that they needed position: relative on their forms that are not given specific instructions on positioning when dealing with google chrome.  I have since made this change myself at www.immoralattack.com and the issue has stopped on that site but still continues on many others so its pretty safe to say that is the issue.

Its only happening on the dev build of chrome for me atleast and I hope this isnt something they plan on implementing on live or this will mess up alot of websites.

Also try turning off auto fill from chrome if its on, while I was looking for this bug I found alot of similar bugs but they delt with auto fill being on.